# log analyzes in Python3 with time differences

Tags: python-3.x, logging, time, difference

I have a file called info.log

this file is full of lines like this :

```
10-30-2020 09:20:53;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:53;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:54;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:54;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:54;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:54;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:55;CLUSTER CRITICAL Computer 345; 2 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:55;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 10:20:56;CLUSTER OK Computer 345; 2 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:56;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:56;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:56;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
10-30-2020 09:20:56;CLUSTER OK; Service cluster; 1 ok, 0 warning, 0 unknown, 0 critical;;;;;;;
```

I need to analyze only the current month.

I need to find when a Computer if getting **Critical** then **OK** and find the time difference of time.

Here for example the difference is between :

10-30-2020 09:20:55
and
10-30-2020 10:20:56

so here the result is 1h00,1s.

finally I need to fill a file with the current month down time like this :

Computer 345 downtime : 1h001minute 1s (don't need to be in letter for hour and minutes)

I have try that now :

```
logfile = "ref_cluster.log.csv"


def mainloop():
    f = open(logfile, 'r')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        if "*" in row:
            row = str(row.strip(";"))
            row_list.append(row)
        else:
            row_list.append(row.split(";"))

    f.close()

    critical_list = []

    for i in row_list:
        if i[1] == "CLUSTER CRITICAL":
            critical_list.append(i)

    print(critical_list)


mainloop()
```

Comment: I would begin by creating a DataFrame from your file data using pandas.  Once you have the data in a Dataframe, pandas offers several methods that would make the analysis easier.

Comment: I have modified the date and time in the logs :

Comment: Did you import the log into a dataframe?  What does the dataframe look like?

Comment: Also, you can now select rows for a specific month